# UIButton isn't responding to touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to make it so that if I buy an item on my app it would allow me to hide the iAd that I have put.
However, when I test it out only my **restore** button is tappable and I cannot tap the **buy** button.

Did I miss something with my app?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSUserDefaults *saveapp = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    bool saved = [saveapp boolForKey:k_Save];
    if (!saved) {
        /// not save code here
    } else {
        ///saved code here
        Label.text = @"item has been purchased";
    }
}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    NSUserDefaults *saveapp = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    bool saved = [saveapp boolForKey:k_Save];
    if (!saved) {
        /// not save code here
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        [banner setAlpha:1];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else {
        ///saved code here
    }
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (IBAction)PurchaseItem:(id)sender {
    _purchaseController = [[PurchasedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    _purchaseController.productID = @"com.myname.appname.iap1";
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:_purchaseController];
    [self presentViewController:_purchaseController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    [_purchaseController getProductID:self];
}

-(void)Purchased {
    Label.text = @"item has been purchased";
    iadBanner.hidden = YES;
    NSUserDefaults *saveapp = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [saveapp setBool:TRUE forKey:k_Save];
    [saveapp synchronize];
}
```

---

### Purchase View

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    _buyButton.enabled = NO;
}

- (IBAction)BuyProduct:(id)sender {
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (IBAction)Restore:(id)sender {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
    [self UnlockPurchase];
}

-(void)getProductID:(ViewController *)viewController {
    _homeViewController = viewController;
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:self.productID]];
        request.delegate = self;
        [request start];
    } else
        _productDescription.text = @"Please enable in app purchase in your settings";
}

#pragma mark _
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    NSArray *products = response.products;
    if (products.count != 0) {
        _product = products[0];
        _buyButton.enabled = YES;
        _productTitle.text = _product.localizedTitle;
        _productDescription.text = _product.localizedDescription;
    } else {
        _productTitle.text = @"Product Not Found";
    }
    products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;
    for (SKProduct *product in products) {
        NSLog(@"Product not Found: %@", product);
    }
}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:[self UnlockPurchase];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;

        }
    }
}

-(void)UnlockPurchase {
    _buyButton.enabled = NO;
    [_buyButton setTitle:@"Purchased" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [_homeViewController Purchased];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are explicitly disabling it with: `_buyButton.enabled = NO;` on `viewDidLoad` and are only setting it enabled when you receive products.. which you can only do by tapping the button in the first place.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer,do you mean the view did load? I have made it yes and is tappable but crashes saying *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid product identifier: (null)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30afbe83 0x3ae5c6c7 0x30afbdc5 0x332119d9 0x6be39 0x332b4da3 0x332b4d3f 0x332b4d13 0x332a0743 0x332b475b 0x332b4425 0x332af451 0x33284d79 0x33283569 0x30ac6f1f 0x30ac63e7 0x30ac4bd7 0x30a2f471 0x30a2f253 0x357632eb 0x332e4845 0x77675 0x3b355ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Look into "setting an exception breakpoint" to give you a more detailed stack trace. If you still can't figure it out, add a new question, that is a different problem

Comment: @user3104325 : it's your code and your layout. either take a screenshot or post the code you have in your `_buyButton`'s selector method

Comment: Above is all of my code for implementing in app purchase for iAd

Comment: @user3104325 : my bad... it seems `BuyProduct:(id)sender` is the selector method for `_buyButton`. You need to put a check in there to see if `_product` is `NULL`. something like : `if (_product) { SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_product]; [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment]; } else { //no _product would have caused an exception }` (_but this is all shoddy work, you need to improve on this_)

Comment: Do you mean putting that code under BuyProduct?? It is not tappable.  What I am doing is after the app gathers the info it enables it  yes.

Comment: When do you call `PurchaseItem:`

Comment: @user3104325 : but after James's suggestion, you made the button _tappable_ on `viewDidLoad` and then you encountered the `NSInvalidArgumentException` exception so i suggested the `if(_product)` check to prevent the crash

Comment: But since PurchaseItem is an IBAction you don't call it programatically. Which button calls that?

Comment: Can we move this to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43357/uibutton-not-responding-causes-crash)

Comment: Ok thanks for the comments I found that i have forgotten to tag the purchase item to the go to buy button screen, however the problem here is I am getting a log saying Product not Found: com.myname.Couturier.iap1.

Comment: Have you created a product with that name on iTunesConnect?